# Show activity's view overlay FrameLayout with Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have the following activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="es.xxx.xxx.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#CCFF0000"
        android:id="@+id/lyNetworkError">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No hay conexión a internet"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In its FrameLayout the app will load other fragments.

This is the onCreate code of activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Constants.setAppContext(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("LoadFragment", "1 "+ loadFragment);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment()).commit();
        }
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, filter);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        lyNetworkError = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyNetworkError);

    }
```

The problem is that LinearLayout (That contains TextView) doesn't show (is posible that fragment render over LinearLayout, because if I remove `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment()).commit();` the LinearLayout appears)

So, how can I show the LinarLayout over fragment (loaded inside FrameLayout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `LinearLayout` and your `Fragment`s are displaying in the correct location on screen when each is shown individually, then you can simply reverse the order of of the `FrameLayout` and `LinearLayout` in your XML.

The problem is that `RelativeLayout` allows its children to overlap. The last item in the `RelativeLayout` will appear "above" or "on top" of other items in the layout. Since you haven't specified any layout constraints for your views, the `RelativeLayout` puts them both in the default position, which is the top left corner. Since your `FrameLayout` is set to fill the parent view's width and height, it will overlay everything else.

If you actually want the `LinearLayout` to appear above the `FrameLayout`, then you can use `RelativeLayout`'s positioning properties ([explained very well here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)) to position your views.
Specifically, you would be looking for something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/lyNetworkError"
    android:id="@+id/container"/>
```

The `android:layout_below` attribute tells the `FrameLayout` that you want it to always be below the view with ID `lyNetworkError` (below as with text on a piece of paper, not in 3-dimensional space).

Comment: Thanks, it works. I know that order in RelativeLayout is important. Thanks